# Test failed on single quoted file path

Tags: bash

I write a bash script that ask user to input file in full path:

```
printf ' Please type the path of ISO file:\n'
read -p ' ' berkas

if [[ -f $berkas ]]
then
    printf " $berkas found\n"
else    
    printf " Could not find $berkas\n"
fi
```

But it failed if file path is single quoted (e.g if i drag file from Nautilus window to script windows):

```
 Please type the path of ISO file:
 '/home/iza/Software/Windows/ISO/Windows7_Ultimate_x64_SP1.iso'
 Could not find '/home/iza/Software/Windows/ISO/Windows7_Ultimate_x64_SP1.iso'
```

What's wrong with the code? I would love if workaround is not involving sed or awk.

Thanx :)

Comment: The `read` command doesn't parse quotes. Those are treated as literal parts of the response.

Comment: I don't think there's a workaround. There's no way to tell if the quotes were added automatically by Nautilus, or you actually have a filename with quotes in it.

Comment: @Barmar would it not be sufficient to simply remove the single quotes from the start and end of the string (as per my answer)?

Comment: What if he has a file whose name starts or ends with quotes?

Comment: @Barmar it's not Nautilus fault. It only affecting to file path with single quotes at the beggining AND at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the quotes from the start and end of the variable in bash using:

```
berkas=${berkas%\'} # remove single quote from end of variable if it exists
berkas=${berkas#\'} # remove single quote from start of variable if it exists
```

If no quotes are present, nothing will be removed.

It's generally considered good practice to put double quotes around your variables, for example
`[[ -f "$berkas" ]]`

Also, rather than using `printf` and appending a `\n` newline character manually, you can just use `echo`:

```
echo ' Please type the path of ISO file:'
read -r -p ' ' berkas

if [[ "$berkas" = \'*\' ]]; then
    berkas=${berkas%\'}
    berkas=${berkas#\'}
fi

if [[ -f "$berkas" ]]
then
    echo " $berkas found"
else    
    echo " Could not find $berkas"
fi
```

As suggested in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739950/test-failed-on-single-quoted-file-path/27740002?noredirect=1#comment43895427_27740002) (thanks Etan), I have added a check that the variable starts and ends with a single quote, which makes the script slightly safer. I also added the `-r` switch to `read`, which you almost always want to use.

#### disclaimer

It is worth mentioning that this approach indiscriminately removes quotes from the start and/or end of the variable, so if it possible that your filenames legitimately may contain quotes in those positions, this will not work.

Comment: Script in question face no problem with single quotes in its file path, as long as the single quotes not at beginning, at the end or at the beginning AND the end of variable. Your answer solved my problem. Thank You.

Comment: @Tom Fenech `[[` [does not allow word-splitting of its arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals), so quoting is not critical. Printf is bash built-in, so its faster than external tool like echo.